# Serial COM Port For ARM in Processing

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, processing, raspbian, serial-communication

I write a program on `Processing Language`, to show the number of serial port in DropDownMenu list for `Intel chip`.

But I am struggling to run the same program on `ARM chip`.

Can you plz guide me on how do I resolve this issue?

```
import processing.serial.*; import controlP5.*;
ControlP5 cp5; DropdownList serialPortsList; Serial serialPort;
void setup() {
  size(700, 400,P3D);
  String[] portNames = Serial.list();
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  // create a DropdownList
  serialPortsList = cp5.addDropdownList("serial ports").setPosition(10, 10).setWidth(200);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < portNames.length; i++) serialPortsList.addItem(portNames[i], i);  
}
void draw() {
  background(128);
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: name of language is proceesing

Comment: How can people help when there's absolutely no information about _what_ the issue you're having is?

Comment: are they called serial ports on arm platforms or something else perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your above program completely but what I understood you are struggling, to show or recognized the Ports of RaspberryPi based on `ARM`.

For that I just search and got a [solution](http://scruss.com/blog/2014/01/07/processing-2-1-oracle-java-raspberry-pi-serial-arduino-%E2%98%BA/) for you. I summaries these steps for you

> Update the system

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

> Install Oracle Java

1. sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk
2. sudo update-alternatives--config java
3. select java version "1.7.0_40"

> Download & Install Processing

1. Go to [Download \ Processing.org](http://processing.org/download/?processing) and get the Linux 32-bit version.
2. tar xvzf processing-2.1-linux32.tgz rm -rf ~/processing-2.1/java
3. ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf
4. ~/processing-2.1/java

> Install the  java Simple Serial connector

1. Download [jSSC-2.6.0-Release.zip](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/downloads/detail?name=jSSC-2.6.0-Release.zip&can=2&q=) and extract it:
2. unzip jSSC-2.6.0-Release.zip
3. mv jSSC-2.6.0-Release/jssc.jar ~/processing-2.1/modes/java/libraries/serial/library/
4. ~/processing-2.1/processing

> Test Processing’s serial support

```
// Example by Tom Igoe

import processing.serial.*; 

// The serial port

Serial myPort;

// List all the available serial ports

println(Serial.list());
```